# Fiz coisa errada no meu código no android studio e não consigo voltar ao que era antes

Tags: android, android-studio

Tem como eu voltar meu código ao que era, antes de eu ter feito coisa errada no android studio? 
Aparentemente eu deletei meu código e só está o gradle script. Tem como eu recupera-lo?

Comment: Acredito que não, mas para que não volte a acontecer comece a estudar versionamento.

Comment: Deve ter ai uma versão local, pode ser que dê...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abra o seu código no editor (tela principal), botão direito, Local History, Show History. Ali você consegue verificar as últimas modificações locais.

Comment: Aparentemente eu deletei meu código e só está o gradle script. Tem como eu recupera-lo? @Leandro Pincini

Comment: Se você tem algum backup, sim, caso contrário, não.

Comment: Obrigado gente!

Answer (score 2):

Caso você não tenha um histórico pelo Local History você não conseguirá recuperar.

Recomendo que você comece a usar alguma ferramenta de versionamento de código para manter um histórico do seu trabalho e possa recuperar o que for feito.

Uma das ferramentas mais famosas é o Git. Através dele você pode manter um histórico de todas as alterações feitas, voltar para alguma versão específica e também trabalhar em paralelo com outro desenvolvedor no mesmo código se for o caso.